# psd в wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Я верстаю обычные страницы. Но есть много заказов типа "psd to wordpress", чем отличается верстка под вордпресс от обычной? Что нужно дополнительно знать

Comment: вот посмотрите - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7akPICFR-AI, остальное практика и решение возникающих проблем по мере их поступления

Comment: Принципы сборки шаблонов. По сути нужно уметь верстать независимыми блоками, большего не требуется